# What built in variable tells you where cmake ExternalProject url tar.gz file gets extracted to?

Tags: linux, unix, build, cmake

When using the ExternalProject feature of cmake and specifying a URL to a local tar.gz file, the file gets extracted to something like this ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$project-prefix/src/$project/*

Is there a builtin cmake variable that points to the implicit/default extract location?

Answer (score 1):

Within *ExternalProject* external archive is extracted into directory known as *DOWNLOAD_DIR*. There are several ways to affect it:

1. Setting *DOWNLOAD_DIR* option for `ExternalProject_Add` command.
2. Setting *PREFIX* option for `ExternalProject_Add` command.
3. Setting *EP_BASE* directory property.
4. Setting *EP_PREFIX* directory property.

See more info in *ExternalProject* [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html).

Comment: This doesn't help. What if you don't explicitly set any of these variables? I'm looking for the variable cmake implicitly uses/generates

Comment: `What if you don't explicitly set any of these variables?` - Then *PREFIX* is assumed to be `<name>-prefix`, and *DOWNLOAD_DIR* will be adjusted according to it. This is noted in the documentation. `I'm looking for the variable cmake implicitly uses/generates` - I don't undesrstand, what you want? Could you provide some *usage example*, which you want to achive?

Comment: No it isn't. Neither DOWNLOAD_DIR nor PREFIX is set for you. The usage is very simple. I'm trying to find a variable that will point to the extracted location of the project so I can simplify the CMakeLists.txt file. For example, in the CONFIGURE_COMMAND I currently have something like this...  

${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/project_turbojpeg-prefix/src/project_turbojpeg/configure --prefix    =${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install --enable-shared=no  

I would like to simplify it like this...  

${VARIABLE_I"M_ASKING_FOR_IN_THIS_QUESTION}/configure --prefix....